# How do I add a attribute to a XmlArray (not element)

Tags: xml, serialization

I want to create some XML like this using Serialization:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Person>
  <Name>Bob</Name>
  <Sex>Male</Sex>
  <links rel="relations">
    <link rel="self" href="/Persons/Bob" />
    <link rel="child" href="/Persons/Lisa" />
  </links>
<Person>
```

Now I know I can set attribute on the `link` items using:

```
Public Class link    
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("rel")>
   Public rel As String = ""

   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("href")>
   Public href As String = ""    
End Class
```

but what I can't figure is how I set the `rel` attribute on the `links` element.  This would be the code for the `Person` Class to set the `links` element:

```
Public Class Person
   ...
   <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArray("links")>
   Public links As New List(Of link)
End Class
```

Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Custom serialization is an option, simply implement the IXmlSerializable interface on your Person's class then in the IXmlSerializable.WriteXml() method control how you want to write the xml yourself.

```
   public class Link
    {
        public string rel { get; set; }

        public string href { get; set; }
    }


    [Serializable]    
    public class Person : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public Person()
        {
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Sex { get; set; }

        public Link[]  Links {get; set;}

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("Name", this.Name);
            writer.WriteElementString("Sex", this.Sex);

            writer.WriteStartElement("links");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("rel", "relations");

            foreach(Link link in this.Links)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("link");
                writer.WriteAttributeString("rel", link.rel);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("href", link.href);
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
        }
    }
```

this is the caller code that will create a Person class then serialize it in the xml you want

```
public SerializePerson()
{

    Link link1 = new Link() { rel = "self", href = "/Persons/Bob" };
    Link link2 = new Link() { rel = "child", href = "/Persons/Lisa" };

    Person person = new Person() { Name = "Bob", Sex = "Male"};
    person.Links = new Link[] { link1, link2 };

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
    StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\temp\serializedBob.txt");
    serializer.Serialize(streamWriter, person);
    streamWriter.Close();
}
```